# Unable to get the edited values to Controller without using wrapper

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, inlineeditsupport

I tried searching for a solution before posting it here but no luck. I have a VFP with account fields and custom InputText field which is used to capture "Other" value which is concatenated(some string manipulations) to store on a field. However, i'm unable to get the edited values back to controller in order for the save to happen as i'm using inlineeditsupport. I know one way this is possible is to use a wrapper class to capture the individual values. However i'm trying to achieve without using the wrapper if possible. Please share your inputs. Thanks you!

Controller:

```
public with sharing class MoreFieldsUpdate_AC{
public String testValue { get; set; }
public String accId { get; set; }
public Account acc { get; set; } 

public MoreFieldsUpdate_AC(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    acc = (Account)controller.getRecord();
    system.debug('acc----'+acc.Id);
    testValue = '';
    /*accId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('acId');
    if(String.isNotBlank(accId))
        acc = [SELECT Id, Name, Beachhead_Attributes__c, Pain_points_with_alternative__c, Benefit_Sought__c, Estimated_Budget__c, Estimated_Campaign_Timing__c, Prospect_s_target_audience_s__c, Exposure_to_TV_Ad__c,Attendees__c, Customer_Segmentation__c, Account_Status__c, Activity_Type__c, Meeting_Type__c, Primary_Lead_Source__c, Campaign__c, Discovery_Meeting__c, Pre_Meeting_Brief__c, Due_Date__c, SM_Presentation__c FROM Account WHERE Id =: accId];
    else
        acc = new Account();*/
}

/*public pageReference save(){
    system.debug('This is not----'+acc.Benefit_Sought__c);
    update acc;
    return null;
}*/
public pageReference cancel(){
    return null;
}
```

}

VFP:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="MoreFieldsUpdate_AC" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <style>
        .multiSelectPicklistRow select {
            max-width: 300px;
        }
    </style>

    <apex:form id="formId">
    <apex:pagemessages escape="false"/> 
    <apex:slds />
    <div style="text-align: center"><br/><br/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" value="Save" status="status" rerender="formId" rendered="true" styleClass="buttonStyle" style="background:LightBlue;width:150px;"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" rendered="true" styleClass="buttonStyle" style="background:LightBlue;width:150px;"/>
    </div>

    <apex:sectionHeader subtitle="{!acc.Name}"/>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Beachhead_Attributes__c}" title="Beachhead Attributes">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton"
                        hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"
                        changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                </apex:outputField>
                <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Pain_points_with_alternative__c}" title="Pain points with Alternative">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton"
                        hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"
                        changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                </apex:outputField>
                <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Benefit_Sought__c}" title="Benefit Sought">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton"
                        hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"
                        changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                </apex:outputField>
                <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Estimated_Budget__c}" title="Estimated Budget">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton"
                        hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"
                        changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                </apex:outputField>
                <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Estimated_Campaign_Timing__c}" title="Estimated Campaign Timing">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton"
                        hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"
                        changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                </apex:outputField>
                <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Prospect_s_target_audience_s__c}" title="Prospect Target Audience">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton"
                        hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"
                        changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                </apex:outputField>
                <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Meeting_Type__c}" title="Meeting Type">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton"
                        hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"
                        changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                </apex:outputField>
                <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Primary_Lead_Source__c}" title="Primary Lead Source">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton"
                        hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"
                        changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                </apex:outputField>
                <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Campaign__c}" title="Campaign">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton"
                        hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"
                        changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                </apex:outputField>
                <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Discovery_Meeting__c}" title="Discovery Meeting">
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton"
                        hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"
                        changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
                </apex:outputField>
                <apex:inputText style="width: 200px;" value="{!testValue}">
                   <apex:outputLabel styleClass="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap"><!--This is from Inspect Element-->
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                   Benefit Sought (Other)
                   </apex:outputLabel>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                </apex:inputText>
                <apex:inputText style="width: 200px;" value="{!testValue}">
                   <apex:outputLabel styleClass="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap"><!--This is from Inspect Element-->
                   Pain Points with Alternatives (Other)
                   </apex:outputLabel>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                </apex:inputText>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a new record, the account `acc` is null. This will create problems. Initialize the variable:

```
    if(String.isNotBlank(accId)) {
        acc = [SELECT Id, Name, Beachhead_Attributes__c, Pain_points_with_alternative__c, Benefit_Sought__c, Estimated_Budget__c, Estimated_Campaign_Timing__c, Prospect_s_target_audience_s__c, Exposure_to_TV_Ad__c,Attendees__c, Customer_Segmentation__c, Account_Status__c, Activity_Type__c, Meeting_Type__c, Primary_Lead_Source__c, Campaign__c, Discovery_Meeting__c, Pre_Meeting_Brief__c, Due_Date__c, SM_Presentation__c FROM Account WHERE Id =: accId];
    } else {
        acc = new Account();
    }
```

Alternatively, I'd recommend just changing your code to use the built-in functionality of the StandardController:

```
acc = (Account)controllger.getRecord();
```

This provides automatic support for loading records from the database based on your markup. You'll need to change your variables to use the standard controller reference:

```
            <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Benefit_Sought__c}">
```

This also removes the need to hardcode the titles.

Comment: i did update my main controller as per your suggestion. However, i'm still unable to save stuff or get the values back to controller. Please let me know what am i missing above. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, i ended up adding a save method & replaced Public pagereference save() method with Public void save() & that helped me saving the record. However, i still don't understand why public pagereference save() didn't work not it wasn't able to retrieve the edited values. I might be missing something out here but if you know the reason please do share your knowledge. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox - as part of my testing i found that i cannot edit single field at a time & save.  Instead I need to edit all fields and then hit save in order for the responses to be captured. Not sure why, please let me know your thoughts. Thanks!